# Is it ethical to present a math work on two different seminars on the same department?

Tags: research-process, mathematics, ethics

I wrote a paper in mathematics and I would like to present it to the right community of experts.
I believe that the work might be of interest both to geometers and analysts. Hence I am thinking to propose it to two seminars on my department: analysis and geometry.

**Is it common to present the same work on two different seminars on the same department? Is there any conflict of interests here?**

Comment: How difficult to invite both groups to the seminar?

Comment: @Nobody : I expect that it is not easy, and only very few people from one group will come to the seminar of the other group. I think usually people come only to their seminar unless there is a famous speaker or something extraordinary.

Comment: What conflict of interest do you think there might be?

Comment: @Buffy : Well, I do not know. But once I visited a conference which was not in my usual field, and met there another person from my field. He kind of hinted (if I understood correctly) that the fact that I am there creates a competition, and he was unhappy about that. This is a different story, but I am wondering if something similar can happen in the situation I posted.

Comment: @MKO Both of your comments sound like something slightly toxic is going on in your community / department, to be honest. Is there a feud of geometers vs analysts? (things I never expected to type)

Comment: Why not pick the most relevant seminar and, in the advertising blurb for your presentation, mention its possible interest to those in the other seminar? I don't know how things are done now and where you're at, but in the 1970s-1990s the departments I was in (or hung around in) would post weekly seminar talk/speaker titles on several bulletin boards throughout the math classroom/office building(s) locations, and it was often the case that if a topic was thought to be of more general interest, then this information was included under the title.

Comment: @xLeitix : As far as I know there is no any feud of different groups. But I do not want that my behavior will invite one.

Comment: Just a comment regarding semantics: there might be good reasons for giving two talks or for giving only one; but this is really not about ethics, and I fail to imagine how this could be related to any conflict of interest.

Answer (score 6):

If these two seminars normally have disjoint audiences, I see no problem whatsoever with this. There is even an advantage to use exactly the same title and abstract in the sense that then it should be clear for people that it doesn't make sense to go to both seminars (which they wouldn't normally do anyway).

However I think it'd be a strange thing to do if seminars of one group are regularly advertised to the other group and there is regular audience overlap, because then "the standard thing" is that people from both groups go to the same seminar if they're interested, and two seminars on the same topic are not needed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any ethical issue here. Perhaps there is an institutional issue (time, space,...) but not an ethical one.

Comments have correctly stated that you can just use advertising among the various groups to get everyone to attend a general talk.

But, there is another option. If you want to give two seminar talks, make them sufficiently different and tailor them to the specific audience. If something in your work is especially interested to those in analysis, build a talk around that. Build another talk around another field. Offer them sequentially, perhaps, once you know how the first was received.

---

I think you are misreading the feedback you got at the conference. The person may have been unhappy that you were there feeling that you might poach on their work and that you had the skills and interest to do so. There is a fair amount of that going on, both fear and poaching. But it wasn't an ethical problem on your part.

Comment: Regarding the conference.  The situation was as follows: I had some recent work with new ideas which I wanted to advertise to other people. In fact I was invited by an organizer of this conference. The person from my field could be unhappy that I share my ideas with people from a different field (this is my guess). Although it should be in a different post, was that unethical on my part?

Answer (score 1):

It is not common. It would be easier to choose just one seminar, or try to arrange a "joint session" of the two seminars.

But if you must present twice, I think it would be OK, as long as you make a best effort to be transparent about it, and no one is surprised, especially the people who run the seminars, and those who choose to listen to both talks don't feel that their time was wasted. If you don't satisfy these conditions, then there's a problem.

I suggest that you make it clear in the announcement for seminar A that yiu will present substantially the same results that you also plan to present in seminar B, but from A standpoint. Likewise for B. And then you make the A and B discussions different enough so that listening to both won't be redundant.

Of course, this assumes that both sets of people who run your seminars agree to your proposal. If only one seminar accepts your talk, then you'll only present there. And if your department is so political that even proposing the above arrangement might unreasonably offend or anger someone, then you should not even propose it.